# Vue js not updating view with files data but able to console log

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on an image upload using vue.js but can't figure out this odd issue.

In my view:

```
{{ form.image }}
```

My data in the vue file:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        form: new SparkForm({
            id: null,
            name: null,
            image: null
        }),
        imagePreview: null
    }
},
```

And the method called when the file input is changed:

```
imageChanged: function(e) {
    var $this = this;
    let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.file;

    if (!files.length) {
        return;
    } else {
        $this.form.image = files[0];
        console.log($this.form.image);
    }
},
```

This will console log the files information correctly, but in the view I just get an empty object.

Can't see anything obvious...

Comment: What is a SparkForm?

Comment: What exactly do you write in the view for the image?? I think it should be something like `<img v-bind:src="form.image" />`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your Vue instance will think the form.image is reactive as it is a property of a SparkForm instance.

You might want to test forcing reactivity in *imageChanged* on the *image* property like so:

```
$this.$set($this.form, 'image', files[0];
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats